# Shiny reactive Unexpected Behavior

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a reactive function that looks up the indices, corresponding to the user's inputs, from a dataframe referred to as `df` in the code below. Just to give you an idea, here's how the dataframe `df` looks like:

```
'data.frame':   87 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Job     : Factor w/ 66 levels "Applications Engineer",..: 61 14 23 31 22 15 57 26 30 13 ...
 $ Company : Factor w/ 102 levels "A10 Networks",..: 95 50 83 71 80 60 20 7 30 51 ...
 $ Location: Factor w/ 64 levels "Ayr","Bangalore",..: 36 22 19 29 59 7 7 55 53 63 ...
 $ Posted  : num  2 3 2 3 1 1 2 5 4 1 ...
 $ Source  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Glassdoor","Indeed": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ url     : chr  "http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=71f1abcd100850c6" "http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=504724a4d74674fe" "http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=d2e78fb67e8c86d6" "http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=df790aa5fc7bdc3c" ...
```

The reactive function mostly uses the `grep` function to do a text search and find the respective indices. Here's the relevant chunk of the code from `server.R`:

```
#Create a reactive function to look up the indices correponding to the inputs
    index <- reactive({
        ind.j <- if(input$j=='') NULL else grep(input$j,df[,'Job'],ignore.case = T)
        ind.c <- {tmp<-lapply(input$c, function(x) {which(df[,'Company']==x)}); Reduce(union,tmp)}
        ind.l <- if(input$l=='') NULL else grep(input$l,df[,'Location'],ignore.case = T)
        ind.d <- which(df[,'Posted']<=input$d)
        ind.s <- {tmp<-lapply(input$s, function(x) {which(df[,'Source']==x)}); Reduce(union,tmp)}
        ind.all <- list(ind.j,ind.c,ind.l,ind.d,ind.s)
        ind <- if(is.null(ind.s)) NULL else {ind.null<- which(lapply(ind.all,is.null)==TRUE) ;Reduce(intersect,ind.all[-ind.null])}

    })
```

I have printed the results of `ind.j`, `ind.c`, `ind.l`,`ind.d`, `ind.s`, and `ind.all` to the console and they all produce the right results. however when I test the results of `ind` it's not quite what I expect so I'm wondering if it's the reactivity or the line of code that doesn't work.

What the `ind` intends to do is to take the list of all the looked-up indices, stored in `ind.all`, and applies the `intersect` function recursively to find the common elements from all the sublists in `ind.all`.

The `index` function works fine for individual filters. however when I enter values for all the indices, the function does not update to the correct list of indices as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538732/shiny-reactive-function-is-not-updating-as-expected) post by [jdharrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690692/jdharrison). I'm going to reiterate his answer here:

```
The problem you have is with the which function:

> which(rep(FALSE, 5))
integer(0)
```

You can change:

```
ind <- if(is.null(ind.s)){
  NULL
}else{
  ind.null<- which(lapply(ind.all,is.null)==TRUE)
  Reduce(intersect,ind.all[-ind.null])
}
```

to

```
ind <- if(is.null(ind.s)){
  NULL
}else{
  Reduce(intersect,ind.all[!sapply(ind.all,is.null)])
}
```